# URL rewrite in wordpress 2 times

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a functionality on first page it lists all states on click of any states in next page it lists cities related to that state and on click f city it shows city page.
State list page - https://benefitsexplorer.com/get-help/unclaimed-money/

originally url for city listing page was
https://benefitsexplorer.com/cities/?lp=unclaimed-money&state=North%20Carolina/

I have added url rewrites successfully for this page using this code

```
function rewrite_state_url(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^get-help/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?
    page_id=2931&lp=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]','top');
}
function register_custom_query_vars($vars){
    array_push($vars, 'lp');
    array_push($vars, 'state');
    return $vars;
}
add_action('init','rewrite_state_url',1);
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars',1);
```

So its showing url like i wanted 
https://benefitsexplorer.com/get-help/unclaimed-money/North%20Carolina

But i am trying now same for city page which will take parameter lastpage, state and city.

so i have added code like

```
function rewrite_city_url(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^get-help/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2944&lp=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]&city=$matches[3]','top');
}
function register_custom_query_vars1($vars){
    array_push($vars, 'lp');
    array_push($vars, 'state');
    array_push($vars, 'city');
    return $vars;
}
add_action('init','rewrite_city_url',2);
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars1',2);
```

now its showing url https://benefitsexplorer.com/get-help/unclaimed-money/North%20Carolina/Locust/

but its showing same page which is showing at state list url https://benefitsexplorer.com/cities/?lp=unclaimed-money$state=North%20Carolina/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combine:

```
 function rewrite_state_url(){
     add_rewrite_rule('^get-help/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2944&lp=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]&city=$matches[3]','top');
     add_rewrite_rule('^get-help/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2931&lp=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]','top');
 }
 function register_custom_query_vars($vars){
    array_push($vars, 'lp');
    array_push($vars, 'state');
    array_push($vars, 'city');
    return $vars;
 }
 add_action('init','rewrite_state_url',1);
 add_filter('query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars',1);
```

Also flush your permalinks (admin > settings > permalinks and hit save without changing anything)

The order in the add_rewrite_rule is important, so do not change it! And perhaps change your function name because now it contains state AND city :)